# how to find middle point of skspritenode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have basic rectangle node with physics body, I want to find middle pint of it, because, I want to both ends of rectangle react different to collision with another objects.I was looking for answer on the Internet, I find that I can use CGGeometry, but I don't have knowledge how to do it. How can I do that?

Comment: you mean the sprite node center ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri yes

Comment: Please See This Tutorial  http://www.garethelms.org/2014/06/help-with-spritekit-position-and-anchorpoint/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add a physics body on each end of your rectangle as a child.  Then you can just detect if the child physics bodies collided without any complicated math

Comment: I don't know if its right thing to do, but I get node height, and use < and >  to get sides of node